# Prove a union is a domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $S$ and $T$ are domains that have at least one point in common, then $S$ union $T$ is also a domain

I wrote: A domain is a set that is open and connected. The union of open sets is easily open.

To prove that $S∪T$ is connected when $S∩T$ is nonemtpy, let $A$ and $B$ be any two distinct points of $S∪T$ and let $C$ be a point of $S∩T$.

Consider point $A$. If it is not point $C$ and is in set $S$, then since $A$ and $C$ are in $S$ and $S$ is a domain, there is a patch entirely in $S$ connecting $A$ and $C$. Since all points of that path are in $S$ they are also in $S\cup T$. Likewise, if $A$ in not $C$ but is an element of $T$, then there is path in $S \cup T$ connecting $A$ and $C$.

So, point $A$ is either the same point as $C$, or is connected to $C$ by a path entirely in $S∪T$.

By the same reasoning, point $B$ is either $C$ or connected to $C$ by a path entirely in $S∪T$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are distinct, at most one of them is $C$. So either $A$ and $B$ are directly connected by a path in $S∪T$ (because one of them is $C$) or are connected by the two-part patch from $A$ to $C$ then from $C$ to $B$, with both parts in $S∪T$.

Since any two points in $S∪T$ are connected by a path in $S∪T$, then $S∪T$ is connected.

My professor commented that I need to prove $S\cup T$ is open, but I don't know what else to include that would show that.

Comment: $S\cup T$ is open because it is a union of the *open* sets $S$ and $T$. Is that what you are after?

Comment: But he already said that at the beginning, so I don't know what more his professor wants for a proof for the openness of the union? Maybe a general proof of this fact?

Comment: The "(at least) one point in common" might be what your professor wants you to mind. It is obvious and easy (as you have said yourself) to show that the union is also open. In your proof, instead of just asserting it, show it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the union of the open sets being open.

Now, the "non-empty" part is easy too.

For the connectendness, I suggest that you go from the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Formal_definition): assume that the union is disconnected. Then there are two non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ that have no intersection and that split your final domain in two: $(S\cup T)\subseteq (U\cup V)$. Now, show that it is impossible: $S$ is completely inside $U$ or $V$. Say, it is in $U$. Then $(S\cap T)\subseteq U$ too. But then, since $T$ is connected, it is entirely inside $U$ too. So, $V$ is empty, which contradicts the definition of non-connectedness.